# Converting AxaptaContainer to either Byte[] or Base64

Tags: c#, asp.net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, business-connector

**Background:** I am trying to display an image from an Ax2012 DB on an ASP.Net page.

**Problem:** The image is stored in the Ax2012 DB as a BLOB (Or well, an Ax Container). I must to convert this in my C#.Net webservice (Connected via the BusinessConnector) to a Byte array, or even directly to a Base64 string.

**What have I done:**
With the code as below, I get an exception that the *imageObject* is not serializable. Which I understand to a certain extent, but how else would I do this then?

*Code Behind:*

```
while (axRecord.Found)
{
    string workerRecId          = axRecord.get_Field("WorkerRecId").ToString();
    string name                 = axRecord.get_Field("Name").ToString();

    string image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        AxaptaContainer imageObject = (AxaptaContainer)axRecord.get_Field("Image");
        new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(ms, imageObject);
        image = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }

    string wppServiceWarehouse  = axRecord.get_Field("WPPServiceWarehouse").ToString();

    dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { workerRecId, name, image, wppServiceWarehouse });
    axRecord.Next();
}
```

*ASP page:*

```
<asp:Image id="employee_ProfilePhoto"   runat="server" imageUrl='<%# "data:image/png;base64," + Eval("Image") %>'/>
```

I also tried casting it to a string, in which case I get no exception thrown, but also no image ;)

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert container to base64 encoded PNG.

You can add this method to `HcmPersonImage` (or any orher) table:

```
public str getImageAsBase64png()
{
    Image   imgObj;
    BinData bd;
    str result;

    if (this.Image)
    {
        imgObj = new Image(this.Image);
        imgObj.saveType(ImageSaveType::PNG);

        bd = new BinData();
        bd.setData(imgObj.getData());
        result = bd.base64Encode();
    }
    else
    {
        result = "";
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then call the `getImageAsBase64png` in `.cs` code behind:

```
axRecord.Call('getImageAsBase64png');
```

Comment: Thanks Matej, will give it a try in the morning!